# How to add custom buttom button in tree view near create button in odoo 11

Tags: jquery, odoo-11

I would like to add custom button in tree view near create button. for particular model tree view only in odoo11.
 this is my sample code:

```js
var QWeb = core.qweb;
var _t = core._t;
var Compare = ListView.extend({
    template: 'CompareListView.buttons',
    render_buttons: function($node) {
        if (!this.$buttons) {
            this.$buttons = $(QWeb.render("CompareListView.buttons", {
                'widget': this
            }));
            this.$buttons.find('.oe_generate_po').click(this.proxy('generate_purchase_order'));
            $node = $node || this.options.$buttons;
            if ($node) {
                this.$buttons.appendTo($node);
            } else {
                this.$('.oe_list_buttons').replaceWith(this.$buttons);
            }
        }
    },
    start: function() {
        this._super.apply(this, arguments);
        var self = this;
    },
});
registry.add('Compare Button', Compare);
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<template>
    <t t-name="CompareListView.buttons">
        <div class="oe_list_buttons">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary oe_generate_po">
                Generate PO
            </button>
        </div>
    </t>
</template>
```

Thanks.